# Undesired error when using aictab() from package AICcmodavg in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the function `aictab()` for model selection. Unfortunately, I'm getting the error:

```
Error in formatCands(cand.set) : 
'cand.set' needs to be a list of candidate models
```

I'm running the script as follows:

```
m1 <- glmer(cbind(Feeding_Foraging,Standing) ~ poly(hour,2)+(1|ID) , data=GLM_df , family=binomial) 

m2<- glmer(cbind(Feeding_Foraging,Standing) ~ Area+(1|ID) , data=GLM_df , family=binomial) 

m3 <- glmer(cbind(Feeding_Foraging,Standing) ~ poly(hour,2)+Area+(1|ID) , data=GLM_df , family=binomial) 

aictab(m1,m2,m3)
```

Does anybody had encountered this error before? Any input is appreciated!

Comment: While you've used this data to ask several questions, you should add your data to **each question you ask.**

Comment: @NelsonGon Thank you for your suggestion. In this case, this is more of a general type of question in which I don't think adding my data will help much. It has to do with the way the function I'm using is implemented rather than transformations on the dataset itself.

Comment: I would think the model you're trying to implement depends on your data type which according to the error is not implemented in the package.

Comment: Also **cand.set :a list storing each of the models in the candidate model set.** Just put your models in a list.

Comment: As @NelsonGon pointted: Cand.models <- list(model1 = m1,model2 = m2,model3 = m3); aictab(cand.set = Cand.models)